# Image on Top of Another

Tags: html, css

I have a colored div that fills the entire top of the page, and an image I need on top of this colored div. The only problem is that the colored div goes on top of the image and the image can't be seen. I tried using z-image:-1 on the div but then my background image goes on top of the colored div. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The image will need to be transparent.  Can I suggest pasting the html on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Theres no `z-image` property... Its `z-index`.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant, z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your divs a css position and they should obey the z-index:

```
.div1 {  
    position: relative;  /* or absolute */  
    z-index: 1;  
    }  

.div2 {  
    position: absolute;  /* or relative*/  
    z-index: 2;  
    }
```

Comment: also note, the default value for position is 'static' rather than 'relative' in case you need to reset it back.